# Android webview loadURL for loading the links in same webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am new to android, I need to load the links in the same webview
i can do it by overriding the function shouldOverrideUrlLoading and i can easily place the   code view.loadUrl(url) inside this function

My question is, is this the correct way to load the links in the same webview
Doing multiple times view.loadUrl() - does this operation creates a stack kind of thing
do this operation cause performance issues?
Is there some other perfect options to do?

can someone clarify on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and return `false` if you want the URL to be loaded in the same `WebView`. See the official docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).